# Why are shell script variables declared without a preceding `$`?

Tags: shell

I noticed that in shell script when we declare a variable, the preceding dollar sign is not needed, although when we want to access this variable later we should add a dollar sign in front of this variable name.

just like:

```
#!/bin/sh
VAR_1=Hello
VAR_2=Unix

echo "$VAR_1 $VAR_2"
```

This is different from other languages, like `Perl` we will always have the preceding dollar sign with the variable name, I just want to know any good reason for shell script to do it in this way, or it's just a convention...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell is a different language than Perl is a different language than C++ is a different language than Python. You can add "with different rules" to each of the languages.

In shell an identifier like `VAR_1` names a variable, the dollar sign is used to invoke expansion. `$var` is replaced with `var`'s content; `${var:-foo}` is replaced with `var`'s content if it is set and with the word `foo` if the variable isn't set. Expansion works on non-variables as well, e.g. you can chain expansion like `${${var##*/}%.*}` should leave only a file base name if `var` contains a file name with full path and extension.

In Perl the sigil in front of the variable tells Perl how to interpret the identifier: `$var` is a scalar, `@var` an array, `%var` a hash etc.

In Ruby the sigil in front of the varible tells Ruby its scope: `var` is a local variable, `$var` is a global one, `@var` is an instance variable of an object and `@@var` is a class variable.

In C++ we don't have sigils in front of variable names.

Etc.

Comment: C++ uses the `m_` sigil =^_^=

Comment: If you insist on making such a joke with an OP who seems to be a novice: The `s_`, `m_` etc. prefixes one often sees in C++ are not sigil. They're part of the variable names and there's nothing special to them. It's one of several known conventions on variable naming: all instance/member variables are prefixed with `m_`, all static (global) ones with `s_` etc. The convention could also be to name all member variables `varnameGOODSTUFF` and all static ones like `varnameDONTDOTHIS`.

Answer (score 1):

In the shell, the `$` sign is not part of the variable name. It just tells the shell to replace the following word with the contents of the variable with the same name, i.e. `$foo` means "insert the contents of the variable `foo` here".

This is not used when assigning to the variable because there you explicitly don't want to insert the old contents; you want to use the variable itself (in some ways this is similar to dereferencing pointers).

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a syntactical convention.

DOS/.bat file syntax works the same way.

1) to create a variable, no metacharacter.

2) to "dereference" the contents of the variable, use the metacharacter.

```
DOS:
set VAR=123
echo %VAR%
```